# When creating package, can I call function inside package while writing other function in the same package?

Tags: r, import, package

Do I need to import my own package?
Or function in the same package can call each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function in the same package indeed can call each other.

Comment: ...even if they are not exported.